# SmallSockets Linker error with iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking

I'm trying to use SmallSockets in my iPhone app to make a TCP sockets connection to a Windows host (server).  When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Socket", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SmallSocketsTestViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Specifically, in red, are the following lines:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Socket", referenced from:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm new to iOS development and VERY new to socket programming, so I'm pretty lost when it comes to these errors.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using to establish a connect:

```
-(IBAction)btnConnect:(id)sender
{
    Socket *socket;
    int port = 11005;
    NSString *host = @"19.5.8.63";

    socket = [Socket socket];

    @try
    {
        NSMutableData *data;
        [socket connectToHostName:host port:port];
        [socket readData:data];
    //  [socket writeString:@"Hello World!"];

    //** Connection was successful **//
    //[socket retain]; // Must retain if want to use out of this action block.
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception) 
    {
        NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception reason]];
        NSLog(errMsg);
        socket = nil;
    }

    //** Disconnect **//
    [socket close];
}
```

If I comment this entire method out, I get no errors.  Not sure if that helps to shed some light on this issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out... I did not select "Add to Target" when I added the library files to the project.  /facepalm

Comment: Yessir.  With much thanks to the fine folks in the StackOverflow community :)